manifold-3d.js with vite and sveltekit
Need some help in getting manifold-3d working with Sveltekit & Vite.
https://manifoldcad.org/three.html
I am trying to understand how to import he wasm file and run it.

Finally got this working. You have to exclude this from the
import Module from 'manifold-3d';

Module().then((manifold) => {
   manifold.setup();
   console.log(manifold);
})

